# ProcessBuilder is executing last

Tags: java, file-io, ffmpeg, processbuilder

I have a segment of code something like this

```
File f = new File("Audio/Testing/mbgitr.wav");
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash/extractAudio.sh", f.getAbsolutePath());
        pb.inheritIO();
        pb.start();
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Oh no!");
    }
    System.out.println(new File("Audio/mbgitr.wav").exists());
```

The bash file converts the audio file to a different format/sample rate and outputs it to the folder Audio.  But whenever I run this script, I get the following output:

```
/home/Ryan/Development/Java/Test/Audio/Testing/mbgitr.wav
mbgitr.wav
/home/Ryan/Development/Java/Test
false
ffmpeg version 2.6.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
[more ffmpeg output]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It seems that the line of code testing if the file exists is executing before the code running the script.  If I were to run the program again, it would ouput "true" because the file was already created in the last iteration.  Is there a way to get the file called by the ProcessBuilder to execute first?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProcessBuilder.start() starts the process as a separate Process and continue to execute. If you need to wait until that process terminates modify the code as shown below. Then you will get the desired output.

```
File f = new File("Audio/Testing/mbgitr.wav");
try {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash/extractAudio.sh", f.getAbsolutePath());
    pb.inheritIO();
    Process p = pb.start();  // Get the process
    p.waitFor();    // Wait until it terminates
}catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println("Oh no!");
}catch(InterruptedException e){
    System.out.println("InterruptedException");
}
System.out.println(new File("Audio/mbgitr.wav").exists());
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why ProcessBuilder does this, but here is one solution.  The line

```
pb.start();
```

will return a Process object, so if that line is replaced with the following two

```
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();
```

The program will pause until the process has completed its execution
'

Note: this must be surrounded by a try/catch block, as p.waitFor() throws an InterruptedException